# Database server connection lost

Tags: sql, postgresql, digital-ocean, psql

When running semi-heavy Postgres queries my SSL connection gets lost end it abandons the query. It says terminating connection due to administrator command.
It would make sense that my server is overloaded, but its only at 80% Disk and 40% CPU usage. And it isn't even time outing me, it does this after like 30 seconds.

I have tried trimming the database and it helps, but every time that after I refresh the data or restructure it this happens.

I don't think it's my code what has bugs in it, but here it also:

```
select
   nb.primaryName,
   sum(tr."numVotes")
from name_basics nb
left join title_principals tp
   on tp.nconst = nb.nconst
left join title_ratings tr
   on tr.tconst = tp.tconst
group by 1
order by 2 desc
limit 10;
```

Comment: Does this happen for other long queries? I wonder if "administrator command" is another way of saying "deadlock victim." Could you have some dependency-contention going on?

Comment: Yes, it does happen almost for every query. I am not familiar with dependency-contention in SQL could you elaborate? I've heard about deadlocks and how they work but I haven't experienced them yet.

Comment: This is not a statement timeout. Look into the PostgreSQL log for signs of a crash or a shutdown request.

Comment: Grasping at straws here, and the text of the error message, if that's what it is, doesn't support it... Dependency-contention is my term for situations that lead up to deadlock. The more tables you include in a query the more likely it is if there is other DML activity going on. Laurenz has a good suggestion about checking logs.

Comment: Don't you need multiple processes to run at the same time for a deadlock to occur? I am only running one query at a time. And also, why would a deadlock be affected by the size of the data?